# check validity of polygon geometry, cast to single polygons

Tags: r, r-sf

I am using the sf package to check validity of polygon geometry, cast to single polygons and remove holes.

This code works:
`polygon = st_cast(polygon, "POLYGON")`

But this code is not working:
`polygon = st_make_valid(polygon) %>% st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>% st_cast("POLYGON")`

I dont understand why and unfortunately cannot follow.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you supplied some example input data, and what your desired output looks like.

Comment: Sometimes st_make_valid() can crate some unexpected geometry types. You can check if this is the case with something like: ```polygon %>% st_make_valid() %>% st_geometry_type() %>% fct_count()``` if there is some non-polygon geometries causing the issue you can extract polys using ```polygon = st_make_valid(polygon)  %>% st_collection_extract("POLYGON")%>% st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>% st_cast("POLYGON")```